how to protect the image from Google cloud storage in the website by referer or host
I have a website to show the image from the google storage, but actually I want to limit the image in the website, it means that even some copy the image weburl, like "https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/blabla.png", and open it in the new chrome tab, he can open it, maybe google cloud storage will check the image referer or host, or ua, if the referer come from my web domain or some other domains, it is ok, otherwise it will show the 403 error.
Besides I also want to upload the image to the google cloud storage.
Because I will show the image in the photoshop plugin and browser, they are totally different scenario. I already tried the signed url function, but it does not work in the photoshop plugin, because it is not the browser.
I want to show the image only in my website and photoshop plugin, not other else places

Have you checked Canonical requests if this would be helpful for your setup?
